# What kind of bike is this

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, vintage, steel

[image]

Good day. Need help regarding a bike I found. No idea what kind of bike it is, does it have value or not, and could I have it restored with its current condition? Any idea/information about this bike would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The cottered crank probably dates it before 1980.  The brakes are very low quality.  There's not really enough there to say much more.

Comment: throw it back in ....

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a 70s/80s single-speed bike, or possibly a 3 speed rear internally geared hub at best.  Will be a steel frame and forks.  Those brake calipers look somewhat flimsy, and the plastic saddle is definitely non-original, possibly from a BMX or kids bike.

The cottered cranks are a really old design, which were common in the 60s and perhaps the 70s.

Its also possible it was a derailleur bike in the past but has had parts changed.

Unless you know its history, it only has value as a daily ride or scrap metal

Comment: Can't make out the right hand rear dropout on that picture but the vertical dropouts also indicate it probably did have a derailleur / gears at some point

Comment: The rear hub looks too small to have internal gears.

Comment: The dropout is horizontal.

Comment: @ojs I disagree - I can clearly see the (rusted) metal around the back.

Comment: @criggie I can see it too. The wheel is inserted from front.